# Default TCP connection backlog value in Windows

Tags: windows, tcp

Which is the default connection backlog value for TCP in Windows? I have tried to find it but no luck.

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

There is no default. It's always specified by the application in the [listen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms739168%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (or equivalent) call.

Comment: humm... not in .NET. I mean, you can listen and start without specify any.

Comment: Languages or toolkits might have defaults.

Comment: The documentation does say "The maximum length of the queue of pending connections. If set to SOMAXCONN, the underlying service provider responsible for sockets will set the backlog to a maximum reasonable value.", so there is some OS default you can choose. I don't know what it *is* however.